# Access inner class Parent KType reflectivly in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I'm trying to instantiate an `inner class` reflectively using Kotlin-reflection library it's not hard except that I need to pass an instance of the parent class to the child class constructor.

Is there any function/way to get the `KType` of the parent class (without using it's name and `Class.forName()`)?

here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class Parent {
    inner class Child()
}
fun main() {
    val childType: KType = typeOf<Parent.Child>()
    val parentType = childType.getParent()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the kotlin-reflect library is returning type for `instance` parameter incorrectly.:

```
val childType = typeOf<Parent.Child>()

val instanceParameterType = childType.jvmErasure.constructors.first().parameters.first().type

//returns com.org.sample.Parent.Child
```

I found a workaround that we can recreate the parent type again (Having all the type parameters saved).

We can convert the `KType` to java types and then get the `Parent` type and `typeArguments` separately and finally recreate the parent type again. here is how it would work.

```
val parentClassObject = childType.jvmErasure.java.constructors.first().parameters.first().type.kotlin
val parentTypeArgs = childType
                .arguments
                //kotlin returns all of the types arguments (parent+inner class) in the same list
                // so we have to minus the inner class arguments to get the parent's
                .drop(childType.jvmErasure.typeParameters.size)
                .takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
                ?.map {
                    KTypeProjection(variance = KVariance.INVARIANT, type = it.type)
                }

//we have to check if we need to recreate the parent type with projections or it did not // have any typeArgs at all
val parentTypeWithProjection =
     if (projections != null) {
         parentType.createType(projections)
     } else {
         parentType.createType()
     }

//com.org.sample.Parent
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a dedicated API for this (a bit surprisingly), but since you have the constructor, e.g.:

```
val constructor = (childType.classifier as KClass<*>).constructors.first()
```

well, its first parameter should be exactly the type of the outer class:

```
val parentType = constructor.instanceParameter.type
```

(not tested; please try `valueParameters[0]` instead of `instanceParameter` if it doesn't work.)

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work either.
I think it's an issue of kotlin-reflection, it returns the child type for instance parameter wrongly.
I have found a work around for this